# Data persistence in ethereum smart contract across deployments

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment

I have developed a SmartContract using ethereum which has an internal struct to store some of the privilege mapping. I find that whenever there is any change in the smart contract and the deployment is happening, the data is lost across upgrades.

**SmartContract**

```
contract PrivilegesContract is SuperAdminContract {

    struct Privilege {
        uint Id;
        string Name;
    }

    uint private privilegeId;
    mapping(uint => string) private Privileges;

    function Add(string name) public EnsureSuperAdmin returns (uint) {
        Privileges[privilegeId] = name;
        privilegeId = privilegeId +1;
        return privilegeId;
    }
}
```

Is there any persistent store that we can use so that i can retrieve the data after a new deployment or be unaffected by the deployments. If there is no persistent datastore, we should have a mechanism to read and initialize the data from the previous transactions in the block. Kindly share the behavior to be followed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to quickly answer your question, no, **data is not persistent across deployments**, but we can make your data persistent in some cases:

Making a comparison with objects is a effective way to understand why this happens: **you can have a car contract/object, when you deploy it, you are creating an instance** of that car.
Behaviour is really similar, you can have multiple instances of a car, and when you alter one of those instances, the rest, are not affected.

**If keeping persistance is a requirement when the application is being used and not only on the development phase**, I'd go for this solution:

Store that mapping into other smart contract, deploy it and access it from the other smart contracts like this:

```
PrivilegesContract privilegies = PrivilegesContract('0xContractAddress') 

string user = privilegies.Privileges[1];
```

That way, you are **separating the data from the logic** (all the functions) but the logic can still access the same data, if you redeploy the logic part of the smart contract you can access the same map.

Comment: Found some good links to read on how the data is stored in Ethereum. https://www.lsenta.io/posts/storage-and-dapps-on-ethereum-blockchain/

Comment: @Saran That link is now broken unfortunately